# Why PyQt effects don't work without QMainWindow?

Tags: python, pyqt

I needed to create simple blurring text and found out that simplest realization fails.. just can't get why? The simplest pattern is:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

lbl = QtGui.QLabel()
lbl.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 100))
lbl.setText('Hello, World!')

effect = QtGui.QGraphicsBlurEffect()
effect.setBlurRadius(20)

lbl.setGraphicsEffect(effect)
lbl.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But this produces just black label:

[image]

And only if I use QMainWindow it works as expected:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
lbl = QtGui.QLabel()

win.setCentralWidget(lbl)

lbl.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 100))
lbl.setText('Hello, World!')

effect = QtGui.QGraphicsBlurEffect(lbl)
effect.setBlurRadius(20)
lbl.setGraphicsEffect(effect)

win.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

with nice result:

[image]

what's difference?

Comment: The first example works on Linux (Python3/PyQt4 and Python2/PySide). It gives the same thing as the second example.

Comment: @tmoreau hmm.. then this is an issue only for windows. at least windows 7 x64